# How does Burp bypass cloudflare?

Tags: postman, cloudflare, burp

I am trying to login to website using http requests. I checked what request sends app using Burp Proxy, and I send exactly the same request to login using Postman.

I noticed something weird. When I send request using Postman via Burp Proxy it works, but when I send the same request without Burp Proxy I get 403 Forbidden and cloudflare verification js in response.
I thought that Burp Proxy changes something in request so I disabled everything:
[image]

But still when I send through Burp it works, and directly it doesn't.

Comment: My guess is that Burp is not rejected by Cloudflare because of it's TLS fingerprint. Each TLS library (or sometimes also the HTTP library has an impact) has it's own TLS fingerprint based on the data and options sent in the TLS handshake. This is used by Cloudflare to detect e.g. TLS library and may be OS. Usually run-time platforms like Python, Java, Dot.Net and so on have a relative stable TLS fingerprint and thus can be identified and rejected if configured.